# Трынь-трава

Tags: этимология

Помните песню про зайцев, который косят трынь-траву?
Насколько я знаю, выражение "трынь-трава" в значении "все равно" ("ему все это трынь-трава") существует в русском языке давно.
А что такое эта самая трынь-трава? Откуда вообще пошло выражение? У меня есть версия, что это какое-то успокоительное или даже наркотическое растение. Я права?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нарыл такую информацию.

**Во-первых, из словаря:**

Трынь-трава -- сенная труха, мелкие огрызки от скошенной травы.

**Во-вторых, целая статья на эту тему:**

У А.С. Пушкина читаем: «Теперь мне честность – трын-трава». Н.С. Лесков свою статью о заселении некоторых пустующих территорий русскими людьми назвал: «Острова, где растет трын-трава». А.П. Чехов заявлял: «Или знать, для чего живешь, или все пустяки, трын-трава», а во «Врачебных советах» давал шутливую рекомендацию: «От насморка полезен настой из трын-травы, пить который следует натощак, по субботам». (Кстати, в одном из старинных лечебников вполне серьезно приводится рецепт такого настоя, в состав которого предлагается включить наряду с привычными ингредиентами типа корня лопуха и весьма экзотические, например, перо павлина и шерсть дикой кошки.) Можно было бы назвать еще очень много имен (И.А. Бунин, Л.Н. Толстой, Иоанн Кронштадский, П.И. Мельников-Печерский и др.), но список получится, пожалуй, слишком длинным. Заметим, что в приведенных цитатах употребляется одно и то же значение понятия, вполне согласующееся с его толкованием в хрестоматийных словарях. И у Даля, и у Ушакова, и Ожегова оно имеет общий смысл: обозначение отношения к чему-нибудь, как к ничтожному, пустому, не важному, не стоящему внимания, то есть всё нипочем, всё равно. И ведь просторечное «трындеть», то есть пустомелить, близко по звучанию, хоть его и считают происходящим от «трынькать», а у Даля оно связывается с трынкой-волынкой. Но откуда же взялось это словечко – «трын-трава»? На этот счет существуют весьма оригинальные версии, например, обосновывающие его происхождения приходом из санскрита, из тюркской лексики (иногда даже этрусков поминают), и т.д. Но большинство исследователей сходится на точке зрения, согласно которой первоначально оно звучало как «тын-трава», а тын, как известно – это не что иное, как забор. Кстати, в болгарском языке имеется очень похожее слово «тиньтрава» (или тыньтрава), обозначающее именно подзаборный сорняк. Правда, на сегодняшний день все же признается, что надежной этимологии нет. Что же до зайцев, то легенды об их косьбе под луной ходили с давних пор. Будто бы в неких местах было предложение использовать зайцев в качестве валюты наравне с деньгами. Население засопротивлялось было, и тогда один человек рассказал, как видел их косящими траву, и это всех, как ни странно, убедило. Кроме того, существовало поверье, что трын-трава обладает успокаивающим свойством, так что не случайно ушастые ее собирали: Храбрым станет тот, Кто три раза в год В самый жуткий час Косит трын-траву. На этом можно было бы и закончить рассказ, но тогда он окажется неполным без расшифровки изначального смысла слова «трава». Впервые интересную догадку о нем высказал В. Даль, когда заявил, что значение корня «трав» связано понятиями еды, корма, питания. Вслед за ним Востоков, поддержав гипотезу, трактовал «тровати, трую» как то же, что «травити, травлю, то есть кормить, кормиться в переносном смысле». А Г. Дьяченко в Полный церковно-славянский словарь включил статью о траве, в которой толковал понятие как собственно корм, аналогично греческому «botane от botos». А Н. Вольский обратил внимание на то, что от этого центрального семантического смысла легко переходить к другим значениям слова: - уничтожать, опустошать, потратить, испортить; - кусать, ловить добычу; - выедать чем-то (например, едкой жидкостью и т.д.); - уменьшать наличное количество (каната и т.п.). И что же в результате мы имеем? Что этимологического подхода к понятию «трын-травы» как к «подзаборному сорняку» оказывается недостаточно, потому что более ранним значением является «подзаборный корм», очевидно, в первую очередь, для животных, хотя там вполне могли находиться и съедобные для человека растения, а нынешней загазованности дорог в давние времена не наблюдалось...

Автор: Валентина Пономарева 
Источник: http://shkolazhizni.ru/archive/0/n-43182/
© Shkolazhizni.ru

Comment: Народный эквивалент утверждения "все - тлен" )

Answer (score 0):

не задавайте вопросов - не услышите лжи.

Answer (score -1):

Двойку автору, не в том направлении "копал", хотя и рядом. В русском языке есть множество непостижимо древних слов, просто сказочно древних. Некоторые вполне успешно маскируются под современность, скажем, слово «дантист» - несмотря на моложавую «внешность», происходит от санскритского "д' ант", что означает «зуб».
Многие языки имеют родство с санскритом, но с течением времени все больше и больше удаляются от первоисточника, и уже почти никто не знает, что слово "пунш" происходит от санскритского "панч", пять, то есть напиток из пяти ингредиентов
Однако в русском, который, по не вполне ясным лингвистам причинам, изменяется медленнее других европейских языков, (потому ,что мы, русские, являемся коренными носителями одного из диалектов САНСКРИТА) по-прежнему можно встретить множество слов-патриархов, которые пережили тысячелетия и все еще вполне узнаваемы, например:
мадху — мед
липтака — липкий
раса — сок (роса)
мрита — мертвый
васант — весна
ваакья — слово, речь

(Если бы моя бабушка, в своих ссорах с дедушкой регулярно употреблявшая фразу : «Что ты там вякаешь?», знала, что говорит на санскрите...)
Есть и менее явные параллели, например, бог смерти - Яма, и в яму мы помещаем тело усопшего... Загадочное слово «говядина» перекликается с эпитетом бога Кришны «Говинда», что означает «защитник коров».
Как писал Брюсов:
...мы - тот великий народ,
Чье имя не будет забыто,
Чья речь и поныне поет
Созвучно с напевом санскрита ...
Удивительно, но и Сеня Горбунков, исполняя свой хит про «трын-траву», был максимально созвучен с санскритом, потому что "трына" — это трава.
Слово практически без изменений осталось в языке, пусть мы уже и не знаем, что это такое, но все равно в речи употребляем. Сейчас уже сложно понять, какая ситуация породила этот древний аналог нынешней фразы «а мне до лампочки». Наверное, такая славянская нирвана — сидишь себе на лужайке, медитируешь, и хоть трава не расти...